# Como multiplicar arrays?

Tags: javascript

**Hice un código simple que suma los arrays, pero como hago para que se multipliquen ?**

```
<h1>The % Operator</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Multiplicacion DE VALORES MEDIANTE CICLOS, ARRAYS Y ACUMULADOR"onClick="ciclos();"/>

<script>

function ciclos() {

  var arrayU = new Array(3);
  var f;
  for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) { // ARRAY LENGTH = 3 = FOR = 0, 1 , 3
    var v = prompt('Ingresa los 3 valores a multiplicar:','');
    arrayU[f] = parseInt(v);
  }
  var total = 0;
  //var multiplicacion;
  //var number;
  for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) {
  total = arrayU[f] + total;
  }
    document.write(total);    
}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**sé que se puede hacer asi, pero es muy manual:**

```
function arrayManual() {
var arrayU = new Array(3);

arrayU[0] = prompt('Ingresa el 1er numero:','');
  arrayU[1] = prompt('Ingresa el 2do numero:','');
  arrayU[2] = prompt('Ingresa el 3er numero:','');


document.write(arrayU[0] * arrayU[1] * arrayU[2]);

}
```

Comment: En el primer `for` de la suma,  solo cambiar el operador `+` por `*`,  así `total = arrayU[f] * total;` y obtendrás la multiplicación

Comment: creo que no explicas bien que es lo que quieres, si es multiplicar varios valores en js lo unico que tienes que hacer es x*y y ya pero eso ya lo sabes(arrayU[0] * arrayU[1] * arrayU[2]) por el cual no entiendo que es lo que quieres saber.

Comment: explícate bien, pues lo que entendemos es que con cambiar el signo de + por * multiplicarías los elementos del arrays, y en tu ejemplo manual de como hacerlo es lo que muestras, entonces, que es lo que quieres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la misma forma que la suma, solo debes cambiar un par de cosas; te presento 2 formas de hacerlo.

la parte de recibir los numero es exactamente igual.

```
var arrayU = new Array(3);
var f;
for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) { // ARRAY LENGTH = 3 = FOR = 0, 1 , 3
  var v = prompt('Ingresa los 3 valores a multiplicar:','');
  arrayU[f] = parseInt(v);
}
```

forma 1: igualar el total a 1 y usar el mismo ciclo que suma el array

```
var total = 1;
for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) {
  total = arrayU[f] * total;
}
document.write(total);
```

forma 2: la primera vez que ingresa al ciclo, asignar el valor a total

```
var total = 0;
for (f=0;f<arrayU.length;f++) {
  if(f === 0){
    total = arrayU[f];
  } else {
    total = arrayU[f] * total;  
  }
}
document.write(total);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! ambos ejemplos me sirvieron , pero mepodrias explicar la funcionalidad de la segunda forma? porque si f es igual a 0 , el total será solo el primer numero ingresado al array y sino el total será la multiplicación pero el total está en 0 y daría 0 , realmente no lo entiendo , podrias explicarmelo?porfavor , gracias

Comment: como _total_ es igualado a cero, no puedes multiplicar los valores por este, porque todo daría cero, para evitar ésto, en la primera iteración del ciclo le asignamos a _total_ el primer valor de _arrayU_; pregunto si es _f_ es cero para saber si es la primera iteración del ciclo, despues de la primera iteracion ya podrás multiplicar cada valor de _arrayU_ normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de preguntar por cada número pide que se ingresen los números una vez, por ejemplo, separado por comas. Luego divides lo ingresado haciendo uso de `split` y finalmente usas `reduce` para multiplicar los números:

```js
const numbers = prompt('Ingresa los números separados por comas').split(',');
const result = numbers.reduce((acc, n) => n * acc);
console.info(result);
```